# Como manter a coesão na minha API REST?

Tags: api, rest

Eu tenho dois recursos de uma API REST
Especialistas e Serviços. Um especialista pode realizar varios serviços.

Eu precisava listar todos os serviços que tenham pelo menos um especialista associado.

get serviços/?criteria
get especialistas/?criteria

Como eu poderia fazer essa requisição sem deixar a api muito confusa e manter a coesão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseando-se em algumas documentações(até mesmo do WebAPI da Microsoft), temos um "padrão REST" para manter a API organizada e "bonita".

seu domínio `api/servicos`

`GET` List => `api/servicos`

`GET` Single => `api/servicos/{ID}` ou `api/servicos?id={ID}`

`POST` Create => `api/servicos`

`PUT` Update => `api/servicos/{ID}` ou `api/servicos?id={ID}`

`DELETE` Delete => `api/servicos/{ID}` ou `api/servicos?id={ID}`

Isso é o básico que as documentações mostram, assim temos um padrão para manter a API mais "coesa".

No seu caso, para manter a API coesa e autoexplicativa, nada melhor que optar pelo simples (KIS - Keep It Simple)

então teríamos: `GET` Listar => `api/servicos/com-especialista`.

Acredito que qualquer pessoal que acessar a documentação de sua API, ao bater os olhos no nome da URL, já irá ter uma boa noção do que ela irá retornar como resposta.

Recomendo dar uma olhada no `Swagger`, ele vai te ajudar muito a documentar sua API, e te poupar muito tempo, hehehe.

https://swagger.io/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Era isso que eu pensava em fazer. Mas queria saber a opinião de outros profissionais.